# Managing multiple Web.config files for multiple deployments

Tags: mono, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, visual-studio-2012

I'm going to develop and test in the following environments:

- Development: my desktop with VirtualBox-ed MySQL database (soon SQLite directly on dev machine)
- Local test: Linux virtual machine on VirtualBox with Mono and MySQL
- Azure staging: Azure website role with SQL Azure backend
- Another Azure staging: Linux VM with Apache/Mono stack and SQL Azure as backend

I publish to these environments using Visual Studio 2012 Publish feature: for example I publish to local test environment using FTP configuration and I already downloaded the Azure publishing profile from Management console.

I have to manage different settings for the environments, **mainly** NHibernate configuration in terms of **connection string** and dialect. But I'll be using different Spring beans in each environment soon or later (i.e. take advantage of blob storage over local file system when on cloud).

Since I'm defining all configuration in Web.config and I'm putting all my efforts in not touching the code when the environment changes with extensive use of Spring.

### How can I tell Visual Studio to publish to each target using a different Web.config file, or better to adapt some nodes of the Web.config to the publishing profile?

Comment: What about [web.config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)?

Comment: Interesting. I'll investigate this

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET - Conditional Web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065115/asp-net-conditional-web-config)