# ASP.NET MVC: Is there a syntax to access a project conditional compile symbol in web.config

Tags: syntax, compilation, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5, conditional-statements

ASP.NET MVC: is there a syntax to access a project conditional compile symbol in `web.config`?

e.g. I could use different databases on a per region basis, or determine whether to require HTTPS, etc.

A similar question in 2012 did not appear to be optimistic about this:
[ASP.NET - Conditional Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065115/asp-net-conditional-web-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.config` files are not part of the build, so I am uncertain what you hope to achieve by doing conditions there that can't be done with a config transform. XML is markup - it doesn't contain any *behavior* by itself. For that, you need a transform engine of some kind.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <!--
        In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
        <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
        Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
        <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
-->
    <sessionState xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
    <trace xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
</system.web>
```

However, conditions *are* supported in MSBuild. This means that you can put conditions inside of your `.csproj` (or `.vbproj`) file by hand editing it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378080/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-publish-to-copy-over-a-native-binary-to-the-bin-dir/28379712#28379712) for more info.

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" $(DefineConstants.Contains('MVC2')) ">
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition=" $(DefineConstants.Contains('MVC3')) ">
    <!-- Due to the windows update MS14-059, we need this hack to ensure we can build MVC3 both on machines that have the update and those that don't -->
    <Reference Condition=" Exists('$(windir)\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll') " Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Condition=" !Exists('$(windir)\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll') " Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <Private>True</Private>
        <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.3.0.20105.1\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <Private>True</Private>
        <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.1.0.20105.408\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <Private>True</Private>
        <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.1.0.20105.408\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

In the above example, if the conditional compilation field contains `MVC2` the first set of references are included, if it contains `MVC3`, the second set of references are included. Note that the symbols are semi-colon delimited.

```
<DefineConstants>MVC2;NET35;</DefineConstants>
```